# $http.get won't display in ionic framework

Tags: php, json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

Hi I am new to JSON and Angular, I have been struggling to display my data to my framework. Only blank page but no error

**This is my controller**

```
 .controller('PetIndexCtrl', function($scope, PetService) {
  $scope.pets = PetService.all();
  console.log($scope.pets);
  })
```

**This is my factory**

```
.factory('PetService', function($http, $ionicPlatform) {
 var markers = [];
 return {
    all: function(){
     return    $http.get("https://192.168.1.10/getEvent.php").then(function(response){
       markers = response;
       return markers;
      });
      }
      }
     });
```

**This is my ionic framework**

```
  <scrip id="pet-index.html" type="text/ng-template">

    <ion-view title="'Rooms'">
     <ion-content has-header="true" has-tabs="true">
      <ion-list>        
      <ion-item ng-repeat="pet in pets" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/pet/{{pet.id}}">
        <h3>{{ pet.prof }}</h3>

      </ion-item>

      </ion-list>

      </ion-content>
     </ion-view>

     </script>
```

**This is my php**

```
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "info");

  $result = "{'success':false}"; 

  $query = "SELECT * FROM viewsched"; 

  $dbresult = $mysqli->query($query); 

  $markers = array();

 while($row = $dbresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $markers[] = array(
     'prof' => $row['Professor'],
     'sub' => $row['Subject'],
     'time' => $row['Time'],
     'room' => $row['Room'],
     'day' => $row['Day']
   );
 }

  if($dbresult){
     $result = json_encode($markers);        
 }
   else
 {

  } 
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,x-prototype-version,x-  requested-with');
  echo($result);
```

I've tried everything and still no data is being displayed. Can someone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This just caught my attention

```
<scrip id="pet-index.html" type="text/ng-template">
```

should be

```
**<script id="pet-index.html" type="text/ng-template">**
```

Comment: i'm sorry a typographical error. it is <script> with the "t".

Answer (score 0):

The $http.get function returns a promise. You call it's function 'then' which also returns a promise not your data.

Instead of

```
$scope.pets = PetService.all();
console.log($scope.pets);
```

try

```
var promise = PetService.all();
promise.then(function(response){
  var markers = response;
  console.log(markers);
});
```